# cxf-codegen-plugin:3.4.2:wsdl2java doesn't produce proper Javadoc

Tags: jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

The classes' Javadoc that's produced by [`cxf-codegen-plugin:3.4.2:wsdl2java`](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) looks like the following here:

```java
/**
 * &lt;p&gt;Java class for RequestType complex type.
 * 
 * &lt;p&gt;The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * &lt;pre&gt;
 * &amp;lt;complexType name="RequestType"&amp;gt;
 *   &amp;lt;complexContent&amp;gt;
```

which, of course, is rendered to the following in Eclipse's Javadoc view, for instance:

```
<p>Java class for RequestType complex type. <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class. <pre> &lt;complexType name="RequestType"&gt; &lt;complexContent&gt;
```

Is this a bug in the plugin?

#### UPDATE

I filed a bug in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8577.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8577:

> This is a known issue fo JAXB 2.3.3, JAXB 2.3.4 has fixed this up.
>
> Please find related discussion here
> https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1471

> The released CXF 3.4.4 has already upgraded to use jaxb-xjc 2.3.4, so no such issue with CXF 3.4.4 anymore